# Why can't I edit my own comments?

Tags: support, comment

The question is fairly self explanatory. I want to fix a spelling mistake in a comment that I made a few hours ago, but I can't edit the comment. Is this a policy on SE or just a malfunction?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78573/

Answer (score 10):

You can only edit comments in the first five minutes after posting them.

Anything longer, either post the correction in a new comment, or delete and post a corrected comment.

Comment: Or, forget about it. (In fact, I am of the opinion that fixing a spelling mistake usually does not merit a "correcting" comment; if nothing else happened and one can simply repost, maybe.)

Comment: But that directly contradicts the edict of Simple Minds, "don't you forget about me"...

Comment: Once comments start to talk, it is best to shut the browser.

Comment: $$\begin{array}{l}\text{When  men on the chessboard}\cr
\text{Get up and tell you where to go}\cr
\text{And you've just had some kind of mushroom}\cr
\text{And your mind is moving low}\cr
\text{Go ask Alice}\cr
\text{I think she'll know}\cr
\text{When logic and proportion}\cr
\text{Have fallen sloppy dead}\cr
\text{And the White Knight is talking backwards}\cr
\text{And the Red Queen's "Off with her head!"}\cr
\text{Remember what the dormouse said,}\cr
\text{"Feed your head. Feed your head"}\end{array}$$

Comment: All these years I thought it was "softly dead." However, Grace Slick published a memoir, Somebody to Love?, in 1998, and the correct word is `sloppy.' Page 108.

Comment: @Will: I don't know if it's because when I first heard the song there were already sufficiently updated lyrics websites to check that, or if I just heard that from the first play. But I always knew it was "sloppy dead".

Comment: both lyrics websites and the lyrics on youtube videos with lyrics are sometimes wrong, and the book could have been wrong as well, but there s a youtube of her at Woodstock, close enough to see how she is forming the words... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2yQLXTuctA in case you can view this one

Comment: @Will: I always preferred Nixon's version, as horribly low quality shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSMf3ZU11Fw

Comment: much silliness..